# How to make a C# library translatable?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, internationalization

I've written a (open source) C#/.NET library that contains a handful of strings that may be displayed to the user. Thus, it would be good to have them translatable.

I've worked at a couple of companies now and they always solved this problem via `.resx` files. However, as companies, they a) know exactly which languages their applications will be translated to and b) have the resources (man power, money) to have all of their strings translated.

As an open source author I neither want to limit the translation of my library to a certain set of languages nor do I have the resources to provide any translation at all.

So, ideally I would only provide the English "translation" for all my strings and user's of my library would have some way of translating these strings into their desired languages without any code changes to my library.

To my (limited) understanding, when using `.resx` files the default language (English) is compiled directly into the assembly/dll whereas other languages are provided as satellite assemblies. So, in theory, user's of my library could provide the satellite assemblies for their desired languages themselves.

Would this work for open source libraries (and if yes, how)? Or are there other, better (recommended) ways of how to deal with this problem?

(Ideally the solution should work with .NET Core.)

Comment: Have you looked at Google Translate? https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries/v3/overview-v3

Comment: @TerryTyson Google Translate provides translations at runtime. That's not what I'm looking for. Also, I could not verify the results for languages I don't speak.

Answer (score 1):

Having users of your library provide translations is not uncommon or unreasonable, I guess. At work we do the same with a commercial library where we also don't have the resources to provide all languages out of the box.

Translation still works with satellite assemblies, the only complicated part is to get the resource names correct (they use the default namespace of the project + any folders if you don't provide a custom name in the project file) so that they are picked up correctly at runtime.

Comment: Can you share any details on how exactly you create these satellite assemblies (e.g. tools, ...)?

Comment: @SebastianKrysmanski: It's just a normal project with resources in them. The only thing that makes them satellite assemblies is their name and location and they usually don't contain code, since they're only used for loading resources.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *JSON* to solve your translation problem

**Slay the Spire** is a really fun rouge-like deck building game
and to translate the game to various languages they came to the community with guidelines and files (which are basically JSON files).

Of course, i don't know the ins and outs of how they did that exactly but it seems you can use the same thing for your library
you can check the computer local language (or any other way) to get the user main language and pull(if exists) the right JSON file before the program starts up

[TRANSLATOR_README](https://github.com/Blagatt/StSFR/blob/master/TRANSLATOR_README.md)

[example for french translation](https://github.com/Blagatt/StSFR)

Comment: In the .NET world it's really better to stay within the means that the platform provides for you here, i.e. satellite assemblies with resources. Note that resources may contain a lot more things than just strings and arbitrary JSON that no other tool in that space understands natively is probably not a good solution for various reasons. _Especially_ for a library where no one will want to make concessions for one piece that localizes differently from everything else.